# StackOverflow when designing comparison operators

Tags: c#, equals, operator-keyword

According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx), I've accompanied my *Equal(Thing)* as follows.

```
public override int GetHashCode() { return Id.GetHashCode(); }

public override bool Equals(object input)
{
  Thing comparee = input as Thing;
  return comparee != null && comparee.Id == Id;
}

public static bool operator ==(Thing self, Thing other)
{
  return self != null && other != null && self.Id == other.Id;
}

public static bool operator !=(Thing self, Thing other)
{
  return self == null || other == null || self.Id != other.Id;
}
```

The problem is that while it was working before I added the operator re-definitions, now I get StackOverflowException. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I totally agree with cHao's answer, However there is another point I would like to make in this case, so here is how I would implement it:

```
public static bool operator ==(Thing self, Thing other)
{
    return !ReferenceEquals(self, null) && 
           !ReferenceEquals(other, null) && 
           self.Id == other.Id;
}

public static bool operator !=(Thing self, Thing other)
{
    return !(self == other);
}
```

Using reference equal will not cause the stack overflow exception since it doesn't use the `==` / `!=` operators, and implementing the `!=` to simply return the `!` of the `==` operator will save you maintenance in case the equality test ever changes. It's an implementation of the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

Comment: I see the smoothness of only changing in one location. However, how would you feel about *return ReferenceEquals(self, other) || self?.Id == other?.Id;* for equality and *return !ReferenceEquals(self, other) || self?.Id != other?.Id;* for inequality?

Comment: I think that However you choose to implement the equality operator, you are still better off with implementing the not equal operator by simply returning the not of the equality operator. That's the whole point of my answer here - Don't implement twice what you can implement only once.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: Looks like your logic's a bit messed up there. `!a || b` is not the same as `!(a || b)`. (Reason #7 why it's better to have the logic in one place and have everything else refer to that. :)

Comment: @cHao I'm sure it is, hehe. And while I agree with the two expressions you show aren't equivalent, I don't see how the two samples in my comment fail. I'll go ahead and assume that this is one of those days when I have bad luck while thinking. Care to give an example so I can see it myself, please?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: For the inequality, let's say `self` and `other` point to two different objects. Then `!ReferenceEquals(self, other)` is true, and the comparison of `Id`s is irrelevant. On the other hand, if they do refer to the same object -- the only case where `Id`s are compared -- then `(self.Id != other.Id)` is false by definition, rendering the check redundant. End result: you get the same result from your inequality expression as you get from `!ReferenceEquals(self, other)` by itself.

Comment: @cHao Oh, so it's a redundancy you meant. I see it now. I was looking for when it gave a wrong result. Thanks a lot. So, if I'd get rid of the redundancy, would you still be able to find en error, please? (I don't intend to do that this way but I'm curious from an academic aspect - in the real code I'll follow your suggestion, as I find it well motivated.) *ReferenceEquals(self, other) || self?.Id == other?.Id;* for equality and *!ReferenceEquals(self, other)* for inequality?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: If you're just going to say `!ReferenceEquals(self, other)` for inequality, then there's no point in defining an inequality operator at all. You want `!(ReferenceEquals(self, other) || self?.Id == other?.Id)`. Which still is nowhere near as clean as `!(self == other)`, but at least works as the opposite of your equality expression.

Answer (score 5):

Once you define an `==` operator that compares `Thing`s, that'll be used when you say `someThing == null`. Likewise with `!=`.

So if you say `self == other`, you end up calling `operator ==(self, other)`. Among your criteria you have `self != null`, which calls `operator !=(self, null)`...which checks if `self == null`, thus calling `operator ==(self, null)`, and round and round you go til you run out of stack space.

I'm pretty sure you can work around this by casting stuff to `object` for the purposes of reference comparison. Or, you can say `Object.ReferenceEquals(self, null)` etc, which doesn't rely on `==` so you don't get the recursion.